# Why won't Vim use my key mapping when I start a new session?

Tags: vim, keymapping

After mapping the F2 key in Vim in the following sequence, it does not work in a new Vim session:

```
:map <F2> :ls<CR>
```

Pressing F2 here displays the files.

```
:mkexrc!
```

Close Vim.

Reopen Vim.

Pressing F2 now does nothing.

The mapping is visible in the _exrc file as:

```
map <F2> :ls
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are simply missing a literal `<CR>`. Type this command in the command line followed by Enter.

```
:map <F2> :ls<CR>
```

If it doesn't work…

1. See if that `_exrc` file is executed by Vim: `:scriptnames` should display it near the top.
2. If it is executed, see if `<F2>` is mapped elsewhere: `:verbose map <F2>`.

Anyway, Vim is not Vi. You should use `:mkvimrc!`. Or a normal `$HOME/_vimrc`.

***edit***

FYI I just created a `~/.exrc` file using `:mkexrc!` and it's not executed by Vim at startup. You should definitely use a normal `$HOME/_vimrc`.

Comment: As you suggested, I used the ':mkexrc!' command.
It put the entry in the c:\vim\vim73\\_vimrc file.
However, the :scriptnames command shows that the file being opened at startup is c:\vim\\_vimrc, not the other.
I pasted the entry into this latter one, appended a <CR> to the entry, and it works.
Does it sound like things are working correctly?  Are there, in fact, supposed to be two _vimrc files in different locations?

Comment: Yes, there's a "system" `_vimrc` that you found and *your* `_vimrc` that should be located at the root of your `$HOME` directory. **You shouldn't do anything to the "system" files.** All your settings are supposed to go into `$HOME/_vimrc`. You should consider editing this file directly if you want your settings and mapping to stick between sessions.